# Python mocking, return different value every call

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am testing a method, `geodata_collect._request_loc_data()`, and within that method I call another method, `geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON(...)` which I need to mock in order to unit-test the first mentioned method.

My problem is that I need `geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON(...)` to return a different value the third time it is called from within `geodata_collect._request_loc_data()`.

I have been exploring `MagicMock` and `side_effect` in order to do this.

```
mock = MagicMock()
mock.side_effect = [self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
    self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True), self._create_request_dict()]

with patch('geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON',return_value=mock):
    geodata_collect._request_loc_data()
```

However, when `geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON(...)` is called from within `geodata_collect._request_loc_data()` the MagicMock class is returned, instead of the actual value.

```
<MagicMock id='140642209064888'>
```

What should be returned:

```
{'status': 'OK', 'next_page_token': 'Next Page EXISTS!!', 'result': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
{'status': 'OK', 'next_page_token': 'Next Page EXISTS!!', 'result': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
{'status': 'OK', 'result': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper MCVE that demonstrates the issue. The more likely explanation is that you are printing the result of a different mock call. What does `print(mock.called())`  produce, for instance?

Comment: Also, I'd use `with patch('geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON') as mock:`, then set `mock.return_value.side_effect` in the `with` block. But that's just my preference. That way you also have access to the mock that actually replaced `loadJSON`, not just the result of *calling* that mock.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that one of the prints was from another call. mock.called returns false

Comment: I hope the question is a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have set the return value of the call to a mock object. So that’s what will be returned! You set return values (side effects) for calls to that call result, so `geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON()()`.

Set the [`side_effect` argument in the `patch()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

```
results = [
    self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
    self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
    self._create_request_dict()]

with patch('geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON', side_effect=results):
    geodata_collect._request_loc_data()
```

Or the [`side_effect` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) on the mock object returned when entering the context manager:

```
with patch('geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON', side_effect=results) as load_mock:
    load_mock.side_effect = [
        self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
        self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
        self._create_request_dict()]
    geodata_collect._request_loc_data()
```

Capturing the mock object the `patch()` context manager creates with `as <name>` is generally a good idea anyway as you now have access to it to assert if it was called.

You can also pass in the `MagicMock` instance you created up front, just pass it in as the second argument, or use the name `new`:

```
mock = MagicMock()
mock.side_effect = [self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True),
    self._create_request_dict(next_page_token=True), self._create_request_dict()]

with patch('geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON', mock):  # or new=mock
    geodata_collect._request_loc_data()
```

`patch()` will then replace `geodata_collect.utils.loadJSON` with that instance, and calling it will use the `side_effect` list set.